# After editing root .bashrc Unable to login even with tty1-6 and drop to prompt command from recovery mod

Tags: login, security, restore, bashrc

I have had the worse two weeks started with Ubuntu 12.04 , and updating to 14.04 had problem , just after a good luck of  successfully installing brand new ubuntu 14.04  I now got the nightmare again so pls help me .

My problem started as I was setting env for golang which has something to do with editing the .bashrc , and I have followed their step : 
Which is adding bellows line to the bashrc after dropping to the root user .

```
    gedit ~/.bashrc
```

And added those lines

```
    export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
    export GOPATH=$HOME/go
    export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

And save file and enter comand source .bashrc 
And try to test with golang just no thing have been effected so I have searched and find someone suggested on a blog post that should add three lines which as he said it will make any change available to logging and non logging ( it will make bashrc write to bash_profile)  those three lines a I can't remember only :

```
    IF
    [......]
    Fi
```

After I did and save change command prompt got hang and stopped operating. I restart to find that I can log in to the screen after entering password. Every time I got back to login screen, just giving me information about my last login.

So I tried with recovery mode and after entering mount remount command and try to enter nano command I got a pink screen.

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Update : Solution.
i reboot into a live usb and then try ubuntu , later open ubuntu and drop to root and mount the partition which has my ubuntu installed on then:

```
cd  /media/ubuntu/sda5/
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /root
```

thing just worked out.

Thanks guy

Comment: Please use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to differentiate between normal text and commands. Did you actually add `Export GOROOT` or was it `export GOROOT`? Did you run `gedit ~/.bashrc` as root? What pink screen? Can you show us your `.bashrc`?

Comment: yes i used gedit as a root. about the pink screen it show only when i use recovery mod and doesn't show any text at all . so is it possible to edit the bashrc as i can get into guest ssession ? or is it possible to restore from live usb of ubuntu ? thanks sir

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the answers to all the questions I asked.